# Is using the student version of 3DS Max and Unity3d legal?

Tags: unity, legal, 3dsmax

I am developing an indie game together with my friend using Unity3D engine. I bought "Silo 3D" for modeling two month ago and for texturing I use 3D coat. We plan to sell our game in the future. For the animations I work with 3DS max (only animation part).

My question is, can I work with a students license? The license for the original version is too expensive for me. I am still at the university and I can not buy the 3DS Max license which costs 4000 €. As an alternative I have the choice beetween Blender (can´t work with this software and don't have time to invest for learning a new program) and Truespace (can´t export fbx animation and specially with bones) so for me, 3DS Max is the best choice to be effective and quick.

Is it possible to prove it when I export my fbx characters from 3DS Max to Unity3D? I mean can they find out that I have used the students license of 3DS Max for the animations after the release of the game? Maybe with help of DRM?

Can I solve that problem when I export the fbx from 3DS Max to Blender and after that export the same fbx to Unity3D?

Comment: This question seemed to go from legitimate question of legality to asking for advice on how to cover up something you know you shouldn't be doing. If you feel like you need to cover it up, I think you already know it's not OK.

Comment: How about just asking Autodesk support? Maybe leave out the bit where you want to inquire about DRM :)

Comment: Not to mention the little problem that any member of the bar cannot give legal advice without becoming liable for that advice.  Therefore any advice you do get is both from amateur legal beagles and worth exactly nothing ;-)  In the meantime, have you read the licenses yourself yet?  Outside the boilerplate, licensing terms of use are usually spelled out clearly.

Comment: Take the hit and learn Blender3D. It'll pay off in the long run.

Comment: I know :/ so what can i do guys? i just wanna make my Dream come true and being really legal.without stealing anything.But 4000 $ is really way expensive for me...

Comment: So use Blender3D. Seriously.

Comment: Blender is really nice for being free, especially coming from Lightwave (most hotkeys and modeling workflow matches) - just don't look at the UI ;)

Answer (score 9):

Forget all that expensive software. Either it's expensive, and you take a hit, or you get used to high-end software, and can't use anything else.

Like I said in my comments, just start learning Blender 3D. It's actually not that bad, the interface just takes a little while to get used to.

If you already know concepts like materials, textures, spot lighting, lofting, etc. then you'll feel right at home.

Comment: is blender good for animation?..biped system (like max)...bones...CAts..usw.cause that's why i need right now..Thx for answering

Comment: @SubZeron Blender is awesome. The main barrier to people using it was that the interface was marginally more difficult to learn than Max or Maya. But in my experience, with nearly the same (and in some cases slightly more) effort it can do what both of those programs do (and actually in some cases far more)

Comment: thx noctrine.. I've been using 3DS Max for over two years now and is really hard for me to switch now.but i think i have to.do you have maybe some good video-tutorials ( How to set up and use Bones. .riging..key frame recording usw) sorry for my bad english.thx

Comment: @SubZeron http://cgcookie.com/blender/

Comment: I used 3DMax for years, too. Blender is terrible in comparison -- 3dmax has a very intuitive set of controls. But that's the price  you pay for free software (in this case).

Comment: thx ashes for everything May Allah reward you greatly.

Comment: thx Noctrine for your link.it´s realy awesome.thx guys

Comment: @SubZeron ameen. Check out MuslimGamer.com if you get a chance :) the forums are awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and No.

Yes it is legal if you won't publish it.
No it is not legal if you'll publish it.

Simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

There's a low cost version of Maya on steam "Maya LT" available for a subscription of $30 per month.

Blender may seem a good alternative but at current state its not good for any real animation work that can be used in a commercial game.

Blender is great for rendering movies or still scenes but sucks very hard at exporting animation and other things for use in Unity or UE4. Its alright for static meshes though.

If you are willing to pay $30 for Maya LT you'll save youself  a fortune of headache you'll have while using blender

Comment: "Blender may seem a good alternative but at current state its not good for any real animation work that can be used in a commercial game." Not true at all. Only a bad craftsman blames his tools..

Comment: oh? Please sir guide me on this here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26020/blender-glitchy-animation-export-fbx-ue4

Comment: @Techie I'm not blaming it , I'm saying its not compatible RIGHT NOW! I've been using it and could not get it to work and community wont help me figure it out, then I imported it to 3ds max and exported again and things got fixed! Blender needs more development

Comment: Things like that shouldn't happen, I agree. I personally never encountered such bugs when using Unity and my personal one.